# SQLite has a different select query than MySQL. How can I fix this?

Tags: c#, mysql, .net, winforms, sqlite

After importing values into the SQLite, I try to extract the values of one graphic by selecting a query, but I get the following error:

> SQL logic error or missing database
>   no such function: year

This is my insert query:

```
string addDat = "";

if (splittedValues[3] != "")
{
    addDat += "INSERT INTO hyddnev (Station, Dat, Vkol) values (" + resultStation + ", '" + splittedValues[1] + "-01-" + (int.Parse(splittedValues[2])<10?"0":"") + splittedValues[2] + "', " + splittedValues[3] + ");";
}

if (splittedValues[4] != "")
{
    addDat += "INSERT INTO hyddnev (Station, Dat, Vkol) values (" + resultStation + ", '" + splittedValues[1] + "-02-" + splittedValues[2] + "', " + splittedValues[4] + ");";
}

if (splittedValues[5] != "")
{
    addDat += "INSERT INTO hyddnev (Station, Dat, Vkol) values (" + resultStation + ", '" + splittedValues[1] + "-03-" + splittedValues[2] + "', " + splittedValues[5] + ");";
}

if (splittedValues[6] != "")
{
    addDat += "INSERT INTO hyddnev (Station, Dat, Vkol) values (" + resultStation + ", '" + splittedValues[1] + "-04-" + splittedValues[2] + "', " + splittedValues[6] + ");";
}

if (splittedValues[7] != "")
{
    addDat += "INSERT INTO hyddnev (Station, Dat, Vkol) values (" + resultStation + ", '" + splittedValues[1] + "-05-" + splittedValues[2] + "', " + splittedValues[7] + ");";
}

if (splittedValues[8] != "")
{
    addDat += "INSERT INTO hyddnev (Station, Dat, Vkol) values (" + resultStation + ", '" + splittedValues[1] + "-06-" + splittedValues[2] + "', " + splittedValues[8] + ");";
}

if (splittedValues[9] != "")
{
    addDat += "INSERT INTO hyddnev (Station, Dat, Vkol) values (" + resultStation + ", '" + splittedValues[1] + "-07-" + splittedValues[2] + "', " + splittedValues[9] + ");";
}

if (splittedValues[10] != "")
{
    addDat += "INSERT INTO hyddnev (Station, Dat, Vkol) values (" + resultStation + ", '" + splittedValues[1] + "-08-" + splittedValues[2] + "', " + splittedValues[10] + ");";
}

if (splittedValues[11] != "")
{
    addDat += "INSERT INTO hyddnev (Station, Dat, Vkol) values (" + resultStation + ", '" + splittedValues[1] + "-09-" + splittedValues[2] + "', " + splittedValues[11] + ");";
}

if (splittedValues[12] != "")
{
    addDat += "INSERT INTO hyddnev (Station, Dat, Vkol) values (" + resultStation + ", '" + splittedValues[1] + "-10-" + splittedValues[2] + "', " + splittedValues[12] + ");";
}

if (splittedValues[13] != "")
{
    addDat += "INSERT INTO hyddnev (Station, Dat, Vkol) values (" + resultStation + ", '" + splittedValues[1] + "-11-" + splittedValues[2] + "', " + splittedValues[13] + ");";
}

if (splittedValues[14] != "")
{
    addDat += "INSERT INTO hyddnev (Station, Dat, Vkol) values (" + resultStation + ", '" + splittedValues[1] + "-12-" + splittedValues[2] + "', " + splittedValues[14] + ");";
}
```

With `splittedValues[1]` I insert Year, from 01 to 12 is months and `splittedValues[2]` is days.

Now I want to get values from SQLite:

```
private void loadButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string command4 = "select vkol from hyddnev where station='"
        + comboBox1.SelectedItem.ToString() + "' and year(Dat) = '"
        + comboBox2.SelectedItem.ToString() + "' order by Dat";

    var StartDate = comboBox2.Text;
    var EndDate = comboBox2.Text;

    SQLiteCommand sqlComm;
    sqlComm = new SQLiteCommand("begin", Connection);
    sqlComm.ExecuteNonQuery();

    SQLiteDataAdapter insertDat = new SQLiteDataAdapter(command4, Connection);
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    insertDat.Fill(dt);

    string s2 = "";
    int i = 0;

    int startYear2 = 0;
    int.TryParse(StartDate, out startYear2);
    DateTime dtStart2 = new DateTime(startYear2, 01, 01);
    chart1.Series["Avg"].XValueType = ChartValueType.DateTime;
    chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.LabelStyle.Format = "yyyy-MM-dd";
    chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.Interval = 1;
    chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.IntervalType = DateTimeIntervalType.Days;
    chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.IntervalOffset = 1;

    chart1.Series["Avg"].MarkerSize = 10;

    foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
    {
        chart1.Series["Avg"].Points.AddXY(dtStart2.AddDays(i), row.ItemArray[0]);
        i++;

        string rowz = string.Format("Avg Q - {0}" + Environment.NewLine, row.ItemArray[0]);
        s2 += "" + rowz;
    }
```

How can I fix this code? I think my problem is from select query?

Can I take some example how to get year? Because in combobox2 I select only year, I do not have months and days...

Thank you..

Comment: [SQL Injection alert](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms161953%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) - you should **not** concatenate together your SQL statements - use **parametrized queries** instead to avoid SQL injection

Comment: Read the [documentation](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html).

Comment: I read this in the morning but Can you give me example how to write this query ? Because I dont know which query exaclly is for my problem ?

Comment: "no such function: year"

Comment: I need the querry like this select vkol from hydnev where station = combobox1 and dat = year - only year because I inserted date time like yyyy-mm-dd I need to select only year ? How ?